# How can i write a javascript code that will return feedback that is not true or false only?

Tags: javascript, arrays, boolean

how will i write a javascript code that will prompt a user to enter their name,check the input and return either good or bad I want the code to return that’s a bad name if the user inputs Shane and I want the code to return that’s a good name if the user inputs any other name.

Comment: Please use a tutorial or book. This is not a code-writing service, it is and question and answer site for actual code. If you have made an attempt or done research and got stuck, please be specific in your question.

Comment: What's wrong with `Shane`? perfectly good name

Answer (score 1):

```
var x = prompt("enter a name")
if(x == 'Shane') { alert('bad name'); } else { alert('good name'); }
```

as a function

```
function isNameGood(){
    var x = prompt("enter a name")
   if(x == 'Shane') { return 'bad name'; } else { return 'good name'; }
}
```

use as this:

```
var good_or_bad = isNameGood();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also achieve this by using Ternary operator.

```
var x = prompt("enter a name");
x == 'Shane'? alert('bad name') : alert('good name');
```

It means that if condition is true then the one after ? will be executed and if false, one after : will be executed.

Here condition is `x=='Shane'`.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the `var name = prompt('What is your name');`

If you need advanced functionality you'll have to bring up your own interface and collect the input via the `var name = document.getElementById('nameInp').value;` function or with jQuery `var name = $('#nameInp').val();`. Now you construct the function and the if statement for how you will check. You've got the value of the persons name at the least.

Quick References:
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_popup.asp